# jquery css set visibility on button click

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to set visibility of indicator on diffrent margin.
i have a slider having two buttons next n prev. i am trying to show the active slide number on click next button i am doing it by this way

```
$("#BtnNext").click(function (event) {
            {
                if ($('#MainContainer').css("marginLeft") == "0px") {
                    $('#FirstPage').css("visibility", "hidden");
                    $('#SecondPage').css("visibility", "visible");
                    $('#ThirdPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                    $('#FourthPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                }
                if ($('#MainContainer').css("marginLeft") == "-1425px") {
                    $('#FirstPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                    $('#SecondPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                    $('#ThirdPage').css("visibility", "visible");
                    $('#FourthPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                }
                if ($('#MainContainer').css("marginLeft") == "-2850px") {
                    $('#FirstPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                    $('#SecondPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                    $('#ThirdPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                    $('#FourthPage').css("visibility", "visible");
                }
                if ($('#MainContainer').css("marginLeft") == "-4275px") {
                    $('#FirstPage').css("visibility", "visible");
                    $('#SecondPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                    $('#ThirdPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                    $('#FourthPage').css("visibility", "Hidden");
                }
            }
        });
```

but the problem is that after sucessfull completion of 1 round when its goes on first slide again then the first indicator is not go in visible mode.
please help me

Comment: Please provide HTML. I have a feeling this can use much less javascript.

Comment: What page is visible after one complete round ??

Comment: You should check out [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com) to see if that helps you.

Comment: actually i have write the jquery for page and thats working fine but the above is for indicator and after 1 round its indicate the second page .i think this happening cause its check the condition and find margin==0px and then its set the indicator on second page as i have write jquery

Comment: @zeMinimalist yes we can do it by another way ,but i think this one is working good.please help me.i cant write the html here due to lack of space

Answer (score 0):

This should work as it sets a default:

```
$('#BtnNext').click(function (event) {
    var marginLeft = $('#MainContainer').css('marginLeft'),
        pages = $('#FirstPage, #SecondPage, #ThirdPage, #FourthPage'),
        page = '';
    switch case (marginLeft) {
    case '0px':
        page = '#SecondPage';
        break;
    case '-1425px':
        page = '#ThirdPage';
        break;
    case '-2850px':
        page = '#FourthPage';
        break;
    default:
        page = '#FirstPage';
    }
    pages.css('visibility', 'hidden').filter(page).css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

If it doesn't work, please set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and link to it in your question.